# Links will not open in iframe target in an iOS standalone web app

Tags: ios, css, html, iframe, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am running into a pickle. When I view my web app within mobile safari via iOS 6, I am able to successfully open up my basic target links  `<a href="link.html" target="mainframe"`into my retrospective iframe `<iframe src="http://www.linkexample.org/" name="mainframe"></iframe>`

Though when the app is opened via standalone all the links exit out of the app and into Mobile Safari. You can see a working example at http://lacitilop.com/m2

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write some javascript to change the `src` of the iframe.

For a start, get your app working so that links will not open Safari by using something like the following (it's using jquery by the way):

```js
if (window.navigator.standalone) {

    $(document).on(
        "click",
        "a",
        function (event) {
    
            event.preventDefault();
    
            var aurl = $(event.target).attr("href");
            if (aurl) {
                location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
            }
            else {
                location.href = this;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

then you'll need to modify it to work with iframes too.

For more iphone app stuff you'll want to look at this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: Thanks Lachlan! That's what I figured but was not sure how to proceed. How would I configure the iframe part? e.g. '
$(document).on(
    "click",
    "mainframe",
    function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var aurl = $(event.target).attr("href");
        if (aurl) {
            location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
        }
        else {
            location.href = this;
        }
    }
);' ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: A bit hard to decipher your code, I've put up a sample here on my site: http://metaltheater.com/test.html that worked on my iphone :)